# Trying to loop over apidata to create 1000 of input dynamically but the page is getting stuck

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, user-interface

```
export default function DynamicsInputs({ apiData }) {
  const column = apiData.map((option) => return{
    header: option.Title,
    accessorKey: <input type='number'/>,
    id:option.ID
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <CustomTable column={column} data={data} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

**I am using custom table to show thousand of input in table cell. when I am fetching data, page is getting stuck while looping and creating the dynamic inputs. Is there a way or optimize the loop to create thousand of input without getting my page stuck**

Comment: What is your use case, why you need 1000 input? By `input` did u mean textbox (`input` for `type` text) ?

Comment: That's expected. What blocks your browser is creating the DOM elements (particularly the inputs). It takes time. You should ask yourself: *"Is it useful for a user to edit thousands of inputs at a time? Is it a good user experience to render thousands of rows/inputs?"*. Can you even fit them on a screen? Probably not. So use pagination or a virtual scroller, which only render 10/20 rows at one time and dynamically change those rows when the page is changed or on scroll.

Comment: Another possible solution is to only render the current value in each cell and toggle the cell contents with an input for editing that value when the user clicks in it. But, really, rendering more rows that can fit the screen is considered sub-par and hurts page performance. The proper solution is to use pagination or virtual scrolling. If you need more help, please update your question with a) a [mcve] with what you've tried; b) (re)search documentation - what similar q/a you found and did not hep, coupled with a brief explanation on why it didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A user wouldn't be able to read 1000 inputs all at once from a custom table.

Generally, It is not a good practice for the apis to provide that amount of information all at once. We always approach this amount of data by using pagination.

If I had the same problem as you do, I would keep those data in my apps memory if the api doesn't provide me a pagination option, and I would create a component with a 2 way virtual scroller(scroll up/down), and while scrolling I would dispose the previous and render the next ones.

If the api would provide me a pagination, then I would use something like [generators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator) to yield the next pages' response(and use the runtime mem for caching).

As about the number of inputs that user should be able to access, well that mostly depends on you applications' design.

Comment: Thank you thandem. I am applying loop on apidata(1000 objects of an array). is there a way to optimize it?